# List index out of Range, maximum loot probelm in python

Tags: python

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def BestItem(n, v, w):
    maxVW = 0
    bestItem = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if w[i] > 0: 
            if v[i] / w[i] > maxVW:
                maxVW = v[i] / w[i]
                bestItem = i
    return bestItem

def get_optimal_value(n, Wt, v, w):
    amount = [0] * n
    value = 0
    for i in range(n):
        i = BestItem(n, v, w)
        a = min(w[i], Wt)
        value = value + a * v[i] / w[i]
        w[i] = w[i] - a
        amount[i] = amount[i] + a
        Wt = Wt - a
    if Wt == 0 or w == [0] * n:
        return value



if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))
    n, Wt = data[0:2]
    v = data[2:(2 * n + 2):2]
    w = data[3:(2 * n + 2):2]
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(n, Wt, v, w)
    print("{:.10f}".format(opt_value))
```

I built this code but got constant error message of 'List index out of Range'. This is one of the maximum loot question. But I don't know where I went wrong as I didn't define any range for any indices.

Comment: If you add the full traceback we might be able to help you – it returns far more useful information than just "IndexError, somewhere". Sample input, current output (if any) and desired result helps us help you as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wanted to add the full traceback, but actually that's all I got for the error message.I suspect this has something to do with ' if Wt == 0 or w == [0] * n:'  because I got more serious error before and I edited this line. However, this time there isn't even a traceback.